# Restreaming an rtsp stream through ffmpeg on iOS

Tags: objective-c, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, rtsp

I have an iOS application that displays an rtsp stream from an IP camera on the local network, I would like to restream it to an external server in real time (Wowza to be specific) the server will take care of converting rtsp to HLS so that the users can view the live broadcast on their devices.

On a computer it would be pretty straight forward:

```
ffmpeg [input-options] -i [input-file] [output-options] [output-stream-URI]
```

But I need to do it programmatically on iOS, and I'm not really sure if it's even possible. Anyone?

Comment: there is an ffmpeg library for ObjectiveC that might help - https://github.com/OpenWatch/FFmpegWrapper - but why go via the iOS device? have the camera push to Wowza and then if you want watch the Wowza stream on the iOS device?

Comment: The camera is connected to a wireless router, which the target device connects to, in the future there will be an embedded computer that will take care of broadcasting and encoding, but now it has to be handled by the iOS app. It needs to display a preview of the video stream and broadcast it to wowza.

Comment: hey @animaonline did you find the solution ?

Comment: @TheMall yep, I had to do some research on how ffmpeg works, then process each frame, copying it from the source stream to a remote rtmp stream (Wowza)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a server (where Wowza is installed) a good idea would be to run FFMPEG there. You can trigger that from mobile (with a script requests that executes ffmpeg command).